# Different Vertical and Horizontal full well capacities for CCD image sensors

Tags: optics, image-sensor, ccd, spectroscopy

I want to use a line sensor for a medical imaging application. I understand that the full well capacity of the pixel is the maximum number of photo-electrons it can store before it gets saturated.
I am specifically looking at this device: https://www.hamamatsu.com/us/en/product/optical-sensors/image-sensor/ccd-cmos-nmos-image-sensor/line-sensor/for-spectrophotometry/S7030-1007.html

The datasheet shows different full well capacities for Vertical and Horizontal. What does it mean to have different values for vertical and horizontal full well capacity? Can it be about the way it performs binning? I am sure I am missing something important from the datasheet.

Here's an excerpt from the datasheet:
|Parameter|Min|Typ|Max|Unit|
|:--------|:--|:--|:--|:---|
|Full Well Capacity Vertical|240|320|-|ke-|
|Full Well Capacity Horizontal|800|1000|-|ke-|

Curiously, the horizontal full well capacity is thrice the vertical full well capacity. But that is not the ratio of the number of pixels.

Comment: I think it refers to saturation when binning.  So you can shift fewer electrons vertically than horizontally, but this might be a good question to take to an application engineer at Hamamatsu.